# System types defined in both mscorlib and netstandard

Tags: .net, nhibernate, .net-standard

I have a vanilla .NET Framework 4.8 Web Application.

I added [NHibernate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate/) and [NHibernate.Extensions.NpgSql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.Extensions.NpgSql/) via NuGet.

Now my project is complaining that all System types (object, int, Guid etc) are defined in both mscorlib and netstandard.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be related to lack of support for .NET Standard 2.1 by .NET Framework 4.8. Npgsql in it's newest release references .NETStandard 2.1, therefore they might create conflicts.
It's more widely described here, on Microsoft page: [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

Comment: Thanks, I suspect it is related, but the NuGet package for the NpgSql extension claims .NETStandard 2.0 support: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.Extensions.NpgSql/